# Facebook API Multiple Search Type

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi and thanks in advance.

I am currently working with the Facebook API, and I want to incorporate the search feature in my system, but the only problem is that I would like to do a search with one or more keywords for one or more type of object.

In other words not only search for posts but also, I would like to be able to search for posts, users and probably even events.

I have tried to put the parameter type like following `type='post,user'` but it doesn't return anything, the result is empty.

Is there a way to do it? The Facebook API manual doesn't say much about the search.

Comment: Have you tried https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/

Comment: Thank you Anvesh i'll take a look at that and see if it will fix my problem.